# Flexslider - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: flexslider

I had a really simple question.

I'm trying to implement Flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) onto my page http://www.gofree.com/123-LAC/ but it does not seem to work (the images appear really large and are listed).

I followed all of the directions on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: css and js path of flexslider is wrong

Comment: Is there something I need to change? I just copy and pasted the code from the site. I tried downloading the .css and the .js and uploading them onto my site but everything just disappears when I link to them. But I was under the impression that I could just copy and paste the code from the site and it would work...

Comment: correct your js and css path..after seeing your site, ur js and css in styles folder... so change the path as styles/jquery.flexslider.js as well as css

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that. The images seem to disappear though. But I'm able to pull up the style sheets when I view source... Is there something else I may be doing wrong?

Comment: yes, u call jquery library twice. .. delete one this <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried deleting each line separately but nothing seemed to happen. Also, I couldn't find <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/… there was either <script type="text/javascript" or script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/…" But I tried deleting each of those lines separately and nothing happened... I'm sorry if I'm not understanding you. I'm new to this.

Comment: view the source and see , u defined the jquery library vs 1.4.4 in body tag, remove it

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery library above the flexslider.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="styles/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

And dont use another jquery library in that page. It create the conflict of both jquery library.

> Always Use jquery latest.. It improve the efficiency and performance
>   of the site

**Learn jquery**

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I think I figured it out.